# JAX-WS: Need XSD (schema) to be included inline in WSDL automatically instead on import from URL/file

Tags: web-services, xsd, wsdl, jax-ws

I have published a Web Service using JAX-WS with Spring. The wsdl obtained using xxxmyService?wsdl shows schema importing from another url:

```
<types>
    <xsd:schema>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://xx.xx.xx.com/"
            schemaLocation="http://MyHost/MyApp/myService?xsd=1" />
    </xsd:schema>
</types>
```

I do not want the schema to be imported using URL as shown above or even place in an external file. I, however, want the schema to be added inline into the WSDL automatically (not copy-pasting the schema manually). Is there any way to do that?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you using contract first or code first approach? In first case, the WSDL you have prepared is published.

Comment: @ŁukaszLech Spring ws only support contract first : http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/why-contract-first.html

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of import is used to import a namespace. Create a Schema named myService.xsd.
When you import it should get the XSD too.

`<xsd:import namespace="http://xx.xx.xx.com/"
             schemaLocation="myService.xsd" />`